# how can i make 4 links to a controller?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

i'm setting up a new project in my laravel

The stuffs i have :

1- PostsController

2- Post model

3- Routes:resource('posts','PostsController')

4- after i login i have a create button for post create

after click on it i have below image :

[image]

My desire:

i want without changing whole project or whole routes resources have these :

after i login i want to have 4 boxes like this( i made it )

[image]

with this property :

after i click any of them i can create post according to their type

> for example if i click on video content i enter to a page with 2 form:
>   like title video and upload video
>
> after i click on text content i enter to page like the image i showed
>   you at the first

it means if i click on video content, resource route take me to create method in postscontroller and create method check if i came from content video link 
return view (posts.create_video) or if i came from sound content link box return view(posts.content_sound) and etc boxes

how can i do all of that please help me thanks

Comment: send a get param with your link? yoururl.test/post/create?type=1

Comment: i edited check again

Comment: there is no one in stackoverflow to answer me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could structure it as following:

- [routes/web.php]

  ```
  Route::get('posts/create/{type}', 'PostController@create')->name('posts.create');
  Route::resource('posts', 'PostController')->except(['create']);
  ```
- [PostController]

  ```
  class PostController extends Controller
  {
      public function create($type)
      {
          if (in_array($type, ['sound', 'video', 'image', 'text'])) {
              return view("posts.content_{$type}");
          }
          abort(404);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: what should i do for store function ? how can i say this validation is just for sound or vide or image ?

Comment: You could add a hidden field contains the file type. <input type="hidden" name="_type" value="{{ $type }}">

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="_type" value="{{ $type }}"> and inside store method i should put if statement for any of those type?

Comment: Basically, yes. But you could use a similar approach the create method according to your app structure.